# How can I sort my chiclet slicer on the basis of customer segments?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a chiclet slicer for my customer segments- Platinum, Gold, Silver & Iron but the order is basis on the count of customers in each of them. I want to sort it in the following order-

1. Platinum
2. Silver
3. Gold
4. Iron

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another numeric column in your segments table to define the desired sort order, e.g.:

[image]

In the report view, in Fields pane, select the segment name column and in `Modeling` tab click `Sort by Column` and select `Sort Order` column:

[image]

This will change the sort order of the segments from alphabetical (based on their name) to the one defined by the values in `Sort Order` column:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a **conditional column** named **SortOrder** in Query Editor mode.
[image]

In data view mode, change the default sort by column to [Sort Order].

[image]

You can know more about the [Sort by column in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sort-by-column)

Answer (score 0):

I got the first solution to work by selecting the segment name in the Fields pane as suggested.  But instead of clicking on the modeling tab, click the tab named Column tools (which only appears after selecting the name in the Fields pane).  There you will find the Sort by column option.